# JShell language encoding in DOS/Windows

Tags: windows, jshell

I'm encountering the issue of having jshell not displaying non-english letters on MS-Windows. On Linux and Mac jshell behaves correctly.

In a DOS window, I try to enter Greek letters, e.g.:

```
jshell> var s = "Γειά"
```

but I can only see

```
jshell> var s = "????"
```

I thought that it had to do with the locale or character set.

```
C:\> chcp  
437
```

so I changed it to UTF-8

```
C:\> chcp  
65001
```

hoping that this would fix the problem, but alas. Please note that in DOS (outside of jshell) I can type Greek letters without an issue.

Even the JShell from inside NetBeans doesn't like non-English letters:

```
[1]-> var s = "Γειά σου";  
|  s ==> "???? ???"
```

So I was wondering if there is some way to set the encoding in JShell itself.

Please note that this behaviour exists only in JShell on Windows. The OS locale has been changed to support the Greek language. However, JShell doesn't want to comply.

Has anybody encountered similar behaviour trying to display letters in JShell Windows from another alphabet?

Answer (score 1):

try

chcp 1253 && jshell

Comment: Set enviroment variable JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=cp737 and for netbeans JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF8

Comment: `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` works for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` environment variables, e.g.

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF8 && jshell
```

But in Linux systems you need to use EXPORT, so

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF8 && jshell
```